# Rmarkdown includes extraneous text in graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm printing a graph in an rmarkdown document using ggplot2 and grid.arrange to plot a line graph and a bar graph arranged vertically. The graph comes out fine, but in the pdf document produced this extraneous text appears below the graph:

> TableGrob (3 x 1) “arrange”: 3 grobs z cells name grob 1 1 (2-2,1-1)
>   arrange     gtable[layout] 2 2 (3-3,1-1)    arrange gtable[layout] 3 3
>   (1-1,1-1) arrange text[GRID.text.6189]

The code that makes the graph is in a function like this:

```
ggnorm <- ggplotGrob(raw.gr)
ggvol <- ggplotGrob(vol.gr)
maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(ggnorm$widths[2:5], ggvol$widths[2:5])
ggnorm$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)
ggvol$widths[2:5] <- as.list(maxWidth)

combo.plot <- grid.arrange(ggnorm, ggvol, ncol=1, top=the.title)

return(combo.plot)
```

The chunk starts like this:

````
```{r overall, echo=FALSE, results="asis", warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
````

And then the function is called, and the result printed like this:

```
overall.plot <- ComboPlot(overall.raw.scores, my.aes, paste("EPI", var.list[i], "through", yrq.list[length(yrq.list)]))

cat("  \n###  \n")

print(overall.plot)

cat("  \n###  \n")
```

I don't know how to get rid of it. Anyone?

(edited adding code)

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? At least isolate the line of code that produces that message and share it?

Comment: It seems like you might be explicitly `print()`in the `grid.arrange`? That shouldn't be necessary with `knitr`.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `print`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, Gregor! That fixed it. Don't know why, though.

Comment: Printing those lines is part of the print method of a `gtable`. You can test in the console too, define some plot `p` and try `grid.arrange(p)` and `print(grid.arrange(p))`.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that, but what is the difference between explicitly saying print(object) and just object? I thought that typing the name of the object implicitly called the print method.